# Using PowerShell to call REST API?

Tags: powershell, rest, powershell-remoting

How can I use PowerShell or Microsoft Graph to perform/call the API below to perform a Backup of the user mailbox in Exchange Online?

https://api.cloudally.com/documentation#/tasks-rest-controller/backupNowUsingPOST_1

`/v1/tasks/{id}/entities/{entityId}/backupNow`

[image]

How to achieve it using the REST API call to the above inside PowerShell script?

Comment: Have a look at [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2) cmdlet

Comment: This looks simple enough for curl. Do you have a curl command available?